# Problem with tomcat and getLocalHost exception

Tags: tomcat, java, localhost

I'm running a Linux server named S1 in a "cloud" server, and when tomcat 6.0.24 starts, I get the exception:

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector pause
SEVERE: Protocol handler pause failed
java.net.UnknownHostException: S1: S1
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1353)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.unLockSocket(ChannelSocket.java:485)
```

Which then leads to:

```
ERROR ehcache.Cache  - Unable to set localhost. This prevents creation of a GUID. Cause      was: Sjira1: S1
java.net.UnknownHostException: S1: S1
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1353)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.<clinit>(Cache.java:143)
```

My hosts file is:

```
127.0.0.1     localhost localhost.localdomain
(valid-ip-address)     S1 S1.(valid domain name)
```

- ping S1 and S1.(valid domain name) return valid ip address
- nslookup S1.(valid domain name) returns valid ip address
- nslookup S1 throws ** server can't find S1: NXDOMAIN

Any ideas about how to fix this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved ... added "search (domainname)" to resolv.conf

Comment: I'm getting the same problem. Did you add `search (S1)` or `search S1` to `resolve.conf`?

Comment: Actually "search (hostname.domainname)"

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same error and tried your suggestions.  Tomcat would start without any errors but my webapp would just hang.  The fix I had, which is really strange, was to cd to ${tomcat_home}/bin first and then execute the startup.sh.  When I reverted back to the original hosts and resolv.conf files and applied this fix, it worked fine.  Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely S1 does not resolve to an IP using a name server only.